# Specific cookie based on language as subdomain

Tags: javascript, cookies, path, dns

I am facing a follwing issue.

Imagine I have a website `https://example.com`

I have 2 language variants of website e.g

```
Site A - https://example.com/en 
Site B - https://example.com/de
```

and I need to create cookie for both of them **with same name but it can have different value**.
So it's simple I will create 2 cookies with different path

```
document.cookie = "myCookie=ThisIsEnCookie; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; domain=.mysite.com; path=/en";
document.cookie = "myCookie=ThisIsDeCookie; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; domain=.mysite.com; path=/de";
```

But now imagine each of this pages have its own store where language paramter is as subdomain in url. E.g

```
   Shop A -  https://en.shop.example.com
   Shop B - https://de.shop.example.com
```

Now the problem is I cant set cookie for specific subdomain. I can create only additional cookie without setting path but then it will be readable by both stores.

So is it somehow possible that if I access Site A **cookie is created and readable only by Site A and Store A ?** (Some for B, because cookie might have different value)

Comment: Your question is not about programming but more webmastering and hence I believe it should be more on topic for [webmasters.se]